# Unit test with react hook fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I don't understand the result I get on this unit test. I expect the second check for `textField.valid` to be `true` and instead it returns `false`.

Below is part of the component I'm testing against:

```
export const FeedbackForm = ({ closeFunc }) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(false)
  const [name, changeName] = useState('')
  const [email, changeEmail] = useState('')
  const [feedback, changeFeedback] = useState('')
  const [patching, setPatching] = useState(false)
  const emailRegex = /^[\w-.]+@([\w-]+.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/g
```

...

```
 <TextField
    id='name'
    label='Name'
    defaultValue={name}
    onChange={(event) => {
      changeName(event.target.value)
    }}
    disabled={patching}
    valid={name !== ''}
    warning='Name cannot be blank.'
  />
```

Below is the test I'm running:

```
  test('should validate the name field', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<FeedbackForm />)
    const textField = wrapper.findWhere((el) => el.type() === TextField && el.props().id === 'name')
    expect((textField).prop('valid')).toBe(false)
    textField.props().onChange({
      target: {
        name: 'changeName',
        value: 'Dude Man',
      },
    })
    console.log(wrapper.debug())
    expect((textField).prop('valid')).toBe(true)
  })
```

The output of `console.log(wrapper.debug())` is the following:

```
<form onSubmit={[Function: handleSubmit]} noValidate={true}>
          <TextField id="name" label="Name" defaultValue="Dude Man" onChange={[Function: onChange]} disabled={false} valid={true} warning="Name cannot be blank." />
```

So why does the test fail?

Comment: Where's the hook? EDIT: Off the top of my head - do you need to wrap it in `act`?

Comment: I think you have to trigger the event through simulate, otherwise how would the enzyme wrapper know to invalidate the component?

Comment: I tried wrapping it in act and it yields the same result. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I needed to change the declaration to `let textField = wrapper.findWhere((el) => el.type() === TextField && el.props().id === 'name')` and then redeclare `textField`

`textField = wrapper.findWhere((el) => el.type() === TextField && el.props().id === 'name')`

to update the value in the DOM